# loading jquery.min only for specific DIV id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to activate a poll script on my`prestashop` site, but during setup there is a little (but Big for me) `problem.script` uses a `jquery.min` file to load data but when i call it in head section , it ruins the whole site. i think its because of using different version of `jquery`.
but actully i cant define my jquery file to only run for that specific Div Section with specific id

**Head section**

```
 <script  src="ezpoll/js/jquery_min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

any help would be appreciated
and thank you all for reading this

Comment: Please write `html` code with `jquery` include.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: I have no idea what your problem is, what you're asking, or how your code is structured. Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking section specifically http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section to see how this site works and to see how to improve this and future questions. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, a useful tool to aid both your debugging of your problem and improve our understanding of both your code and your question.

Comment: Of course you can't. Consider to use [`jquery.noconflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to run 2 version of jquery on the website.